# Selenium Driver for Edge getting constant version error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to figure out why I am getting the same problem everytime using a python script for autocomplete an exercise on https://at4.typewriter.at/ .

Every time it says:

```
 DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50195/devtools/browser/4e38eb0d-6ef9-4d13-9553-820801ba1832
[9492:9508:1205/011008.125:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(387)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "typewriterbot.py", line 167, in <module>
    driver = Login()
  File "typewriterbot.py", line 52, in Login
    driver = webdriver.Edge("driver\msedgedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of MSEdgeDriver only supports MSEdge version 98
Current browser version is 96.0.1054.43 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

I already updated the driver through Microsoft and checked if the python binaries (if it is called so) were at the high enough version to run the code.

Best regards
CreaGab

Comment: The message seems to be telling you that Edge itself is not up-to-date, have you updated Edge to the latest version?

Comment: I did search for an update. The newest version is installed because I'm running Edge in a virtual machine :)

Comment: Downgrade MSEdgeDriver to a version that supports MSEdge version 96. If you are using the dev or canary channel version of MSEdgeDriver, you'll probably need the dev/canary version of MSEdge

Comment: I searched for a older version and after 3 versions it finally works! It's writing for me and the driver is now working! Thx

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I encountered a similar issue with Selenium, however I was working with Chrome. I did a little digging around and noticed the library that helped me get around this version error can also be applied to Edge. Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
```

In a nutshell, once you assign **webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())** it will update Edge driver to its latest version.

More details for this library can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, fortunately I only had to to downgrade the Edge driver to a specific version so that it would run the .py :)